# Java String to byte conversion is different

Tags: java, string, byte

All

I have a question for send byte array to Server.

The Each ID has Text Value.

```
private String ID = "0001";
byte STX = (byte)0x02;
byte A = (byte)0x41;
byte NUL = (byte)0x00;
byte ETX = (byte)0x03;
byte CR = (byte)0x0D;
byte LF = (byte)0x0A;
byte[] buffer = { STX, Byte.decode(ID), A, NUL, ETX, CR, LF };
```

I expected buffer values

```
buffer [02, 48, 48, 48, 49, 65, 00, 0D, 0A]
```

but buffer value has

```
buffer [02, 01, 65, 00, 0D, 0A]
```

How Can I Convert to "0001" to [48, 48, 48, 49], String to Decimal Conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The method [`Byte#decode(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#decode%28java.lang.String%29) returns a single `Byte`** that is added as an element to you `buffer` array.

The String `"0001"` represents the octal value `0001` which is `1`.

You won't be able to add multiple array elements with one variable in a `{ }` initialization notation.

Instead, you can do the following

```
String ID = "0001";
byte STX = (byte) 0x02;
byte A = (byte) 0x41;
byte NUL = (byte) 0x00;
byte ETX = (byte) 0x03;
byte CR = (byte) 0x0D;
byte LF = (byte) 0x0A;
List<Byte> bytes = new ArrayList<Byte>();
bytes.add(STX);
for (char c : ID.toCharArray()) {
    bytes.add((byte)c); 
}
bytes.addAll(Arrays.asList(A, NUL, ETX, CR, LF));

Byte[] buffer = (Byte[]) bytes.toArray(new Byte[0]);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(buffer));
```

prints

```
[2, 48, 48, 48, 49, 65, 0, 3, 13, 10]
```

Note that this solution might not work as you expect when the `char` value goes over the value range that `byte` can hold.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
 ...

    ByteBuffer buffer2 = ByteBuffer.allocate(10);
    buffer2.put(STX);
    buffer2.put(ID.getBytes());
    buffer2.put(A);
    buffer2.put(NUL);
    buffer2.put(ETX);
    buffer2.put(CR);
    buffer2.put(LF);

    byte[] data = buffer2.array();
    buffer2.clear();
```